# Creating an array of objects using C++

Tags: c++

My assignment is asking me to create an array of objects with a pointer pointing to them.  This is the general construction.

```
class Student;

derived class Network Student: public Student;

class Roster;
```

I am declaring the array in class Roster as follows:

```
Student* classRosterArray[5];
```

In my function I am trying to allocate new memory for each new object( which is a derived class of Student)

```
if (degree == DegreeType::NETWORK) {

        classRosterArray[lastIndex] = new NetworkStudent();
    }
```

I keep getting errors on the declaration such as:

```
missing type specifier- int assumed
```

I don't understand this as I assumed that `Student` was the type specifier.

Comment: Is `derived class Network Student: public Student;` pseudo code, a typo or the real content of some file? Because that's no valid C++.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) plus complete error message and information about compilation (compiler, version, flags, etc.).

Comment: you must have the line for which the compiler produces *"missing type specifier- int assumed"*, show it

Comment: the class declarations are pseudo code just to show the general layout of the program.

Comment: @db714 If you want answer instead of pseudo-answer, show us code instead of pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student;
```

is not a full class declaration. It is what is known as a forward declaration.

Try

```
class Student{};
```

which makes it a full declaration (although, of course, in practice you will want to put something inside the `{}`).

You'll need to do likewise for your other classes.

Comment: Watch your nomenclature: `class Student;` is a declaration: it declares the the identifier `Student` names a class type. `class Student {};` is a definition (and also a declaration): it defines the shape of the class type `Student`. The word "forward" in "forward declaration" is only an informal addendum; it does not exist in the formal C++ language specification.